# Generating an Excel document from a SQL Server query with Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I've inherited the responsibility for a web server that our team uses internally.

The issue that I'm facing is that we are migrating to a newer server and some of the functionality is now broken because of the move.

I was able to fix everything else on the site, the only thing that doesn't work is the function to generate an Excel document from a SQL Server query.

I can post more of the code if necessary but this is where I am currently hung up. I get this error when attempting the Excel export

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
>   Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]'
>   /Vacation/VacationLog/VacationSummary/Display.asp, line 24

These are lines 20 through 26

```
end if 
varState = Request.QueryString("state")
varVacationIdentifier = Request.Form("Vacation")
VacationArray = Split(varVacationIdentifier,",")
varVacation = VacationArray(0)
varSub = VacationArray(1)
varPort = VacationArray(2)
```

I'm not that familiar with Visual Basic so any help to what to look at next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you are facing! If possible provide the full code of the function or event.

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET? .ASP is the extension for a file in [Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-classic/info), which is very weakly related to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
' put the value from the field Vacation into a variable:
varVacationIdentifier = Request.Form("Vacation")


' split the variable into parts put them into an array
 use the comma as delimiter
VacationArray = Split(varVacationIdentifier,",")'

'Put the first array value into a variable:
varVacation = VacationArray(0)
```

and there is crashes because i guess there was no single comma in that field, resulting in an empty array. basically this means that you have to add some input validation.